# How do I cast an argument to a class in Rubymotion Android?

Tags: android, rubymotion

Handling file uploads I need to pass an array of uri's to a `android.webkit.ValueCallback`

```
def handleResult(intent)
  uri = Android::Net::Uri.parse(intent.getDataString)
  file_path_callback.onReceiveValue([uri])
end
```

The problem is that onReceiveValue expects an array of `android.net.Uri` and the following error is raised:

```
Java exception raised: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]
```

How do I cast the array to the proper types?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding a `Util` class and implementing a class method in java.

In `util.rb`

```
class Util
end
```

In `util.java`

```
// ValueCallback.onReceiveValue only accepts an array of Uris
// This isn't supported by Rubymotion so we create a special method to allow
// sending arrays of Uris
public static void onReceiveValue(
    final android.webkit.ValueCallback callback,
    final android.net.Uri uri) {
    android.net.Uri[] urlList = new android.net.Uri[] { uri };
    callback.onReceiveValue(urlList);
}
```

Then pass the callback to the Util method:

```
def handleResult(intent)
  uri = Android::Net::Uri.parse(intent.getDataString)
  Util.onReceiveValue(file_path_callback, uri)
end
```